# Is there a way to directly access a web page that PopUps from a MVC application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

The site I have is written in .NET MVC. This site has a footer in the view with some links that when clicked pops up a window. The popup is done using javascript and ajax. All of the popups work fine.

What I am after is a way to directly access the faq page in the popup via a URL. When I attempt to access the page directly via the URL "http://www.mysite.com/faq" I get page not found. I would like to access the page either as a popup or a full web page with the following:

```
http://www.mysite.com/faq
```

The code in the footer follows:

```
<a href="#" data-link="faqs">FAQs</a><span>|</span>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $("div.Footer a").click(showPopUp);
    $("a#close-button").click(hidePopUp);
});

function showPopUp(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(e.target).data("link");
    loadHtml(link);
}

function loadHtml(link) {
    if (!$.isShowingStaticContent) {
        $.isShowingStaticContent = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: true,
            url: '/home/' + link,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $("body").prepend(jqXHR.responseText).find("#close-button").click(hidePopUp);
            },
            error: function(){$.isShowingStaticContent = false; }
        });
    }
}

function hidePopUp(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("div:first").remove();
    $.isShowingStaticContent = false;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the FAQ: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask your question is in danger of being closed unless it's rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

The route for the FAQ page would actually be site.com/home/faq because the faq action is in your home controller (at least that's how it looks from just looking at your ajax call). If you want to be able to access site.com/faq, you need to either move the faq action it it's own controller, or edit your routes in App_Start/RouteConfig.cs